# using math pow, changing variables between double and int (android bitmap)

Tags: android, math, bitmap

I'm looping through a bitmap pixel by pixel to determin if that pixel is within a circle placed on the bitmap. i've been kindly given the math to determin this but the algorithm is using pow(double, double). i've tried casting and using Integer.doubleValue to no avail. has anyone got any ideas how to get the pow method to return an int which the sqrt() method needs? centreX and centreY are both int too.

[update]
sorry sqrt returns and needs a double:)

thanks mat.

```
for (int i=0; i < bgr.getWidth(); ++i) {
                for (int y=0; y < bgr.getHeight(); ++y) {

                    int aPixel = bgr.getPixel(i,y);

                      if( sqrt( pow(i - centreX, 2) + ( pow(y - centreY, 2) ) ) <= radius ){

                        bgr.setPixel(i,y,Color.MAGENTA);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're looping through the entire bitmap? Really?

Comment: @ignacio vazquez-abrams why do i sense this is a bad idea:)

Comment: Circles have a *very* well defined square bounding box, and with a little more math an octagonal bounding box can be found, and only those pixels need be checked.

Comment: @ignacio vazquez-abrams ok thanks for that i'll search around and look in to it. i've noticed that the app runs slowly now due to the method call overhead of checking every pixel in the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all,

My bad the pow() method is static from the Math class so needed the dot operator to access it statically. silly mistake:) eg Math.pow(d,d);

Answer (score 0):

divide your code into more lines so its easier to spot the line that causes the error:

Keep in mind that this is pseudo code :-)

```
double a = pow(i - centreX, 2);
double b = pow(y - centreY, 2);

int c = (parse to int) (a + b)

int root = sqrt( c )
```

Then debug those lines to spot the error :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right and your question is how to cast double to int, why don't you use floor or ceil function inside `Math`?

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce a constant `rsquared = radius*radius` and change your condition to `if ((i-centreX)*(i-centreX)+(y-centreX)*(y-centreX) <= rsquared)`. No floating point needed.